# Getting an OAuth2 token in scratch orgs

Tags: apex, oauth2, scratch-org

I'm trying to get an OAuth2 token in a scratch org, I set up a connected app and tried just about every way that I could think of.  I attempted to use my scratch org url and test, this is what my constructed request looks like.. And Ideas?

`https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?client_id=3MVG9eQyYZ1h89Hfv65svH6r.cVHnDV_W3sRTxUpxQK3HJce_hZQdBUcqSL4AzPFWq0ieiDs5XY4ThQiWa1lv&client_secret=66E3451CD2458CBDEE0AD3BAE9FC85DCB021492E1EC7E23D1298FEB628C6B0B3&password=mypasswordhasa&init&username=test-zg06ribwccg2@example.com&grant_type=password`

I've also appended my security token to the end of my password with no success, is it possible to hit `/services/oauth2/token` in a scratch org?

Comment: Be sure to change your password as soon as you see this comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Special characters in the username or password need to be URL encoded. While I ordinarily don't approve of posting access credentials in a forum, especially here, it's apparent that the `&` in your password is causing the problem. The `&` should be encoded as `%26`. And yes, you should be using your scratch org's host name to get the token; Scratch Orgs do not participate in the test.salesforce.com login domain. Also, the username should be encoded as `test-zg06ribwccg2%40example.com` (the @ symbol should be `%40`).

Comment: Are the `-` okay?

Comment: @EricSSH Yes, that's fine. See [Percent Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for characters you must encode, plus their %-encoded values.